# how to extract data from the database and pass it to the function in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I`m beginner Django user, please help me. I have multiple records in a sqlite3 data table. Please tell me how to read this data from the database in Django and write it to the views.py function.

This is my models.py

```
class Value(models.Model):
    capacity = models.FloatField('Емкость конденсатора')
    amplitude = models.FloatField('Амплитуда')
    frequency = models.FloatField('Частота')
```

This is my views.py

```
def voltage(array, a, c, w, tim):
    t = 0
    for i in range(100):
        array.append(c * a * math.sin(w * t - math.pi / 2))
        tim.append(t)
        t = t + 0.1


someArray = []
tim = []
voltage(someArray, a, c, tim)
```

in c I want to write capacity, in a - amplitude, in w - frequency.

I hope I can get data from the database into the views.py function

Answer (score 1):

```
#views.py

from models import Value

#in the view
vals = Value.objects.all()
for v in vals:
    c = v.capacity #and so on
```

Comment: I wrote this code, but when i pass variable a or c to voltage function it says "Name 'a' (or 'c') can be undefined"